# Hibernate fully fetch a lazily fetched object on command

Tags: java, hibernate

So I have an object with collection. I want to lazily load it at first , but an object can be sent over a network which makes it necessary to fetch all the fields.

```
      @Entity   
      class Foo
      {
       @Id
       int id;
       @Column
       String name
       @OneToMany
       List<Foo2> = new ArrayList<>();
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... call a method on the list (like `size()` for example) to initialize it, or use [`Hibernate.initialize()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize%28java.lang.Object%29).